# MigraDoc documentation

Tags: c#, pdf, migradoc

I am trying to create a PDF using MigraDoc and C#. At the moment I am stuck as I wasn't able to find an exhaustive documentation of that library, just some code examples on the [official github page](https://github.com/empira/pdfsharp.Samples) of the project (which I can not understand very well without a detailed description of the methods involved).

I managed to find [this doc](https://hiraokahypertools.github.io/PDFsharp/pdfsharp-wpf/html/annotated.html) for PDFsharp and I was wondering if anything like that exists for MigraDoc.

Edit: I forgot to say that I also saw the examples on [this page](https://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocSamples.ashx), but there isn't any "real" documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is in the source code.

Visual Studio shows that documentation for each class or method when you enter them into code (Intellisense).

A stand-alone help file created from source code can be found here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/files/pdfsharp/PDFsharp%201.31/

The samples show you the basic pattern of MigraDoc with AddParagraph, AddTable, AddRow, AddText. Please check the various AddXxx methods and ask questions if you cannot figure out how to achieve what you need.

Comment: I will surely try the addXxx methods in a few days and check this answer as solution or comment again here.

Comment: Hi. I tried to download the code as you said and I solved all my problems. 
Thank you very much for your answer